# Logarithmic equation in which base of the logarithm is not same.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

If $log_{9}x=log_{12}y=log_{16}(x+y)$ then find $y/x$.

I simplified this into

$\frac { \log { x }  }{ \log { 9 }  } =\frac { \log { y }  }{ \log { 12 }  } =\frac { log(x+y) }{ \log { 16 }  } $

I equated two terms to get three equations. But that didn't give the answer. So when I looked at its step by step solution then I found

$\frac { \log { x }  }{ \log { 9 }  } =\frac { \log { y }  }{ \log { 12 }  } =\frac { log(x+y) }{ \log { 16 }  } =\frac { log\frac { y }{ x }  }{ log\frac { 12 }{ 9 }  } =a$

After this step I understood the solution but I don't how the last term equal(i.e $\frac { log\frac { y }{ x }  }{ log\frac { 12 }{ 9 }  } $) equal to others terms.

Any help would be appreciated. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If $\frac{\log x}{\log 9} = \frac{\log y}{\log 12}$, then
$\frac{\log x}{\log 9} - \frac{\log y}{\log 12} = 0$, i.e. $\frac{\log 12 \cdot \log x - \log 9\cdot \log y}{\log 9\cdot \log 12} = 0$ and thus
$$
\log 12 \cdot \log x - \log 9\cdot \log y = 0\,.
$$
Rewriting,
$$\begin{align*}
0 &= \frac{\log 12\cdot  \log x}{\log 12 - \log 9} - \frac{\log 9\cdot \log y}{\log 12 - \log 9} 
= \log x + \frac{\log 9\cdot  \log x}{\log 12 - \log 9} - \frac{\log 9\cdot \log y}{\log 12 - \log 9} \\
&= \log x + \log 9\cdot \frac{\log x - \log y}{\log 12 - \log 9}
= \log x + \log 9\cdot \frac{\log\frac{x}{y}}{\log\frac{12}{9}}.
\end{align*}$$

Rearranging the terms,
$$
-\frac{\log\frac{x}{y}}{\log\frac{12}{9}} = \frac{\log x}{\log 9} 
$$ 
that is
$$
\frac{\log\frac{y}{x}}{\log\frac{12}{9}} = \frac{\log x}{\log 9} .
$$

Comment: I got it! That was a great explanation. Can this be done in easier way because that was quite long.

Comment: @SatvikPandey: most likely... I didn't try to be concise, mostly to give a clear derivation.